# A question about Rudin's PMA, definition 10.46

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The definition which we need to understand the theorem:

The class $\mathscr C'$ is the class of continuously differentiable functions.
[image]

[image]

I don't understand how do we get $(135)$

-

$N$ $=$ ($\alpha_2$$\beta_3$ $-$ $\alpha_3$$\beta_2$)$e_1$ $+$ ($\alpha_3$$\beta_1$ $-$ $\alpha_1$$\beta_3$)$e_2$  $+$ ($\alpha_1$$\beta_2$ $-$ $\alpha_2$$\beta_1$)$e_3$

and
$(137)$
$N$ $\cdot$ $(Te_1)$ $=$ $0$ $=$ $N$ $\cdot$ $(Te_2)$

I would be grateful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Phi$ is a surface via both $(u,v)$ and the $N$ representation ($130$).

The equations in ($133$) describe the differentials of the function $\varphi_i$ at the point $p_0$ using the two generic differential operators $D_1$ and $D_2$, which correspond to the differential operators in the numerators of ($129$), i.e. $D_1=y,D_2=z$ etc... for each term., and lead to ($135$) via the Jacobian.

($137$) uses the dot product and is straight-forward as each positive term has a negative partner.

$$N = (\alpha_2\beta_3-\alpha_3\beta_2)e_1+(\alpha_3\beta_1-\alpha_1\beta_3)e_2+(\alpha_1\beta_2-\alpha_2\beta_1)e_3$$

$$T(e_1)= \alpha_1e_1+\alpha_2e_2+\alpha_3e_3$$

$$N\cdot T(e_1)=(\alpha_2\beta_3-\alpha_3\beta_2)\alpha_1+(\alpha_3\beta_1-\alpha_1\beta_3)\alpha_2+(\alpha_1\beta_2-\alpha_2\beta_1)\alpha_3=0$$

Similarly

$$T(e_2)= \beta_1e_1+\beta_2e_2+\beta_3e_3$$

$$N\cdot T(e_2)=(\alpha_2\beta_3-\alpha_3\beta_2)\beta_1+(\alpha_3\beta_1-\alpha_1\beta_3)\beta_2+(\alpha_1\beta_2-\alpha_2\beta_1)\beta_3=0$$

Comment: thank you I got $(135)$ but can you explain the $(137)$ more explicitly?

Comment: Thank you. I got it

Comment: Pretending that we don’t know about cross product is silly.

Comment: @JMP excuse me, but why is $\alpha_2$$\beta_3$ equal of $\alpha_3$$\beta_2$

Comment: It's not. $\alpha_2\beta_3\beta_1$ from $e_1$ is cancelled by $\alpha_2\beta_1\beta_3$ from $e_3$.

Comment: @JMP you get $\alpha_2$$\beta_3$$e_1$ . what about $\alpha_2$$\beta_3$$\beta_1$? how did you get it?

Comment: $N$ and $T$ are vectors, the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two vectors is a scalar. The components of $e_i$ are multiplied together, so the first term is $\alpha_2\beta_3\beta_1$ and the last term is $-\alpha_2\beta_1\beta_3$. These cancel, as do the otrhers.